# how to convert html file to byte array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to convert a photo into an array of bytes. I'm loading this photo with html like this:

```
<input class="form-control"
           type="file"
           name="filename"
           tooltip="Buscar foto"
           ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">
```

`onFileSelect` function saves the file in a variable of my scope. This is the code.

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
        $scope.selectedFile = $files;
    };
```

Now, I need to convert this file into an array of bytes, to display it as a picture later using `data-ng-src =" data: image / png; base64, {{selectedFile}} "` but i don't know how to do this. Any idea? Thanks

**EDIT**
This is a picture of $files log.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader

So, in your case you could do:

```
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($file){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e){
    console.log("about to encode");
    $scope.encoded_file = btoa(e.target.result.toString());  
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString($file);
};
```

Note there are several ways to read in files with the FileReader object. Great for reading as binary, text, and array buffers!

Comment: i'm getting this error: `Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`. I think that maybe is because the parameter is a `File`

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like you're using a list of files. Would you mind posting the log of what $files is?

Comment: Yep, you're definitely in a list. We'll want to drill down to the actual file object. Try $file[0] and let me know if that works.

Comment: You're right. Using the first element of the list is working. Thanks!!